# Creating a specific CSS grid with an unlimited number of elements

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I trying to create a CSS grid that will have specific columns (row by row) where I can add any number of DIVs, which will be added in specific order:

```
[1] [2] [3]
[4] [5]
[6] [7] [8]
[9] [10]
etc
```

But also I want to be able to access the div of each "subgroup" (1-3, 5-8, 4-5, 9-10 etc) to edit their "insides" by CSS

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to use `grid-template-columns`, but all I've achieved is displaying elements three in a row via `repeat(3, 1fr)`

Comment: each 5 items, an empty column/cell?

Comment: Sorry, no: each odd row has three elements, each even row has two elements.

Comment: Are the cells all the same width or do the cells in the two column rows expand to fill the row?

Comment: @AHaworth, in odd row - same width, but in even row it is same width to, but  div. For example, the parent element has a width of 300, in odd lines three to 100, and in a even - two to 150.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a 6 columns configuration:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(6,1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.container > div {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
.container > div:is(:nth-child(5n + 4),:nth-child(5n)) {
  grid-column: span 3;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Temani, thank you! Your code implements exactly the idea that I put in.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this as well

```css
.three{
    display: grid;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 30vh;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 30%;
    gap: 5%;
}
.three div{
    background-color: burlywood;
}

.two{
    display: grid;
    height: 30vh;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 30%;
    gap: 5%;
}

.two div{
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="three">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="three">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="three">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: This is not a generalisable solution as you'd have to go through the HTML changing it whenever an element was added or removed etc. And the question specifically spoke about a CSS grid, not an HTML restructure.

Answer (score -2):

do something like `<div style="grid-row: 1/2">3</div>` and `<div style="grid-row: 3/4">8</div>` but not sure how you would do it with unlimited elements